# Azure DataFactory from Blob storage to SFTP server

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

After hunting through the net I can find lots of examples of retrieving data from SFTP but none to send from Blob storage to SFTP.

Basically I attempted to do this using a Logic App but Azure only supports files less than 50MB (which is really dumb).

All the Azure docs I have read reference pulling but not pushing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-sftp-connector

etc etc..

Maybe someone with better googling skills can help me find the docs to help me out.

I'm using DataFactory V1.0 not 2.0 cheers

Comment: The document also states - `Data factory currently supports only moving data from an SFTP server to other data stores, but not for moving data from other data stores to an SFTP server. It supports both on-premises and cloud SFTP servers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check this table to see if a data store is supported as source or sink in a data movement activity.

In this case, SFTP is supported as source but not as sink, this means its possible to extract data from it but not store data on it.

Hope this helped!